# Updating div content after submiting ajax form in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, updatepanel, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-ajax

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <ul class="purpose">
    @{ 
        var purpose = CommonMethod.getPurpose("");
        for(int i=0;i<10 && i<purpose.Count();i++)
        {
            <li><a href="#" >@purpose[i].Text</a></li>
        }
     }
    </ul>
</div>
```

on selecting the above single purpose from list it will show below ajax form for updation

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdatePurpose", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updateDiv" }))
{
    <div  class="profile">
    @Html.Hidden("PurposeID")
    <table>

        <tr>
             <td>Purpose</td>
             <td>:</td>
             <td> width="30%">@Html.TextBox("Description")</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Admin Password</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>@Html.Password("Passwd1")</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
   </div>
}
```

After Subting below action is called

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePurpose(string PurposeID,string Description, string Passwd1)
{

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (!Membership.ValidateUser(User.Identity.Name, Passwd1))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Admin Password");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var id = Convert.ToByte(PurposeID);
            var pur = db.Purposes.Where(p => p.PurposeID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            pur.Description = Description;

            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Result = "Data Updated Successfully.";
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

On submitting above ajax form Updatepurpose I want to show validation message errors if admin password is invalid and also I want to load myDiv content if modelstate is valid and give successful updation message to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Ajax.BeginForm` HTML Helper and do some handwritten jQuery code. You can do any kind of customization then.

I would keep your Markup like this (removed AjaxForm, Used a normal form declaration, Added a css class name to submit button)

```
<div  class="profile">
<form>
@Html.Hidden("PurposeID")
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Purpose</td>
         <td>:</td>
         <td> width="30%">@Html.TextBox("Description")</td>         
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Admin Password</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>@Html.Password("Passwd1")</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btnSavePurpose" />
```

And add some javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

    $(".btnSavePurpose").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var item=$(this);
       $.post("@Url.Action("UpdatePurpose","Admin")", 
                         item.closest("form").serialize(), function(data){
           if(data.Status=="Success")
           {
             //Let's replace the form with messsage                
             item.closest(".profile").html("Updated Successfully");
           }    
           else
           {
              alert(data.ErrorMessage);
           }

       });   
    });   

 });

</script>
```

Now update your Action method to return the `JSON` data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePurpose(string PurposeID,string Description, string Passwd1)
{        
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (!Membership.ValidateUser(User.Identity.Name, Passwd1))
        {
            return Json( new { Status="Error",
                               ErrorMessage="Invalid Admin Password"});
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var id = Convert.ToByte(PurposeID);
            var pur = db.Purposes.Where(p => p.PurposeID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            pur.Description = Description;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json( new { Status="Success"});
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

What it is doing is, When user clicks on the button with that CSS class, it will serialize the container form  and send it to the `Action` method. Then the action method  do its job and if the Validation fails, It will send a `JSON` in the below format back to the client

```
 { "Status": "Errorr", "ErrorMessage": "Invalid Admin Password"}
```

If it is fine, It will do the DB update and send a JSON back to the client in this format.

```
 { "Status": "Success"}
```

And in the callback of out `ajax(POST)` function, we are checking the value of `Status` in the `JSON` and showing appropriate message to the user.

Simple & Clean :)

Comment: Thanks.. but how I will update the div(mydiv) content?. I want to ask that if purpose gets updated then how I can reload only that div content.

Comment: @user1506422: You can either set the value to be updated in the JSON response and read from there and set in the Div like `$("#yourDivId").html(data.Something)`. Or make a jQuery load call to reload some partial view.

Comment: Can We highlight the errors  for perticular field using above post method As mvc validation errors highlights textbox as red when validation fails.

Comment: By using  $.post() function I am not getting the uploaded file on server side. I have added enctype to form. How I will retrive the uploaded file.

Comment: for file upload, you may need some jquery plugin like uplodify. normal ajax post cant send a file